# Update different columns in multiple tables by joining them

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I want to update simultaneously 3 columns of 3 tables by making two joins and select by sdo.status=active :

```
select sdo.status, sc.status, sps.status from table1 sdo, table2 sc, table3 sps 
where sdo.uuid_table1 = sc.uuid_table1
and sps.uuid_table3 = sc.table3
and  sdo.status='active';
```

My aim is to update status of this selection like that in pseudo-code :

```
update set
sc.status='inactive',
sps.status='inactive',
sdo.status='inactive';
```

Is it possible to do that in oracle ? I tried so much requests, no one update take into account join.

I have no primary / Foreign key in my tables.

Comment: You may want to Google the following error: **ORA-01776**.

Answer (score 3):

Not possible, at least not directly.

You could try to create a view, create an INSTEAD OF trigger on that view and - in that view - update separate tables.

Here's an example based on Scott's tables.

View:

```
SQL> create or replace view v_emp_dept as
  2    select e.deptno, d.dname, e.empno, e.ename, e.job, e.sal
  3    from emp e join dept d on e.deptno = d.deptno;

View created.
```

*Instead of* trigger:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger trg_iu_ved
  2    instead of update on v_emp_dept
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    update emp e set
  6      e.ename = :new.ename,
  7      e.job   = :new.job,
  8      e.sal   = :new.sal
  9    where e.empno = :new.empno;
 10
 11    update dept d set
 12      d.dname = :new.dname
 13    where d.deptno = :new.deptno;
 14  end;
 15  /

Trigger created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> select * from v_emp_dept where deptno = 10;

    DEPTNO DNAME               EMPNO ENAME      JOB              SAL
---------- -------------- ---------- ---------- --------- ----------
        10 ACCOUNTING           7782 CLARK      MANAGER         2450
        10 ACCOUNTING           7839 KING       PRESIDENT       5000
        10 ACCOUNTING           7934 MILLER     CLERK           1300

SQL> update v_emp_dept set ename = 'ClArK' where empno = 7782;

1 row updated.

SQL> select * From emp where deptno = 10;

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE        SAL       COMM     DEPTNO
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- -------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7782 ClArK      MANAGER         7839 09.06.81       2450                    10
      7839 KING       PRESIDENT            17.11.81       5000                    10
      7934 MILLER     CLERK           7782 23.01.82       1300                    10

SQL>
```